# Facebook reader app

Tags: facebook

Would it be possible to create e.g. a Windows desktop application that reads Facebook content of an account using web services of Facebook and then to display a custom selection of the content in the desktop application?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Mostly depends on _what kind_ of content ... not everything that is freely accessible via the UI, is also freely accessible via API. For most content, at least published by user profiles, you would need to get the permission to read their content from those users first.

Comment: @CBroe Permission would effectively make it rather worthless. Could you explain how come that one can read all content via a browser but not via an API?
I mean how can a API ask a user for permission.

Comment: Because an API would allow you to easily gather massive amounts of data, whereas if you tried to scrape it from the web site, it would be much easier to detect and block. Asking users for permissions happens via the [login dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking), of course.